# Calculate offset for ScrollToVerticalOffset from line number in a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, richtextbox, offset, scrollviewer

I want to move the content of a `RichTextBox` to a specific line of the content. The `RichTextBox` provides the method `ScrollToVerticalOffset` from the embedded `ScrollViewer`. The method is documented in MSDN, but the measurement unit of the parameter named offset is not [specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx). The Type is `double`.

A [`VerticalOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.verticaloffset.aspx) property of a `TextBox` is documented as in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit).

So I tried to calculate the offset from the font size. The font size is given in pixels. The resulting formula is

```
offset = fontSize * 96 / 72  *  lineNumber;
```

But this jumps way behind the desired line. For now I am using this calculation:

```
offset = fontSize * lineNumber;
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that long time passes from asking this question, but still have not found the right answer to it !!

I used this code now, that's good for me really:

```
var offset = (lineNumber * (fontSize + 2)) - richTextBox.ActualHeight / 2;
richTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
```

If you know one solution better than this way, please help me.

Comment: Your calculation sounds good to me. But I am not able to validate the calculation at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```html
TextPointer myTextPointer1 = Paragraph.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(20);
TextPointer myTextPointer2 = Paragraph.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-10);

RichTextBox.Selection.Select(myTextPointer1, myTextPointer2);
           
DependencyObject currObj = RichTextBox.CaretPosition.Parent;
FrameworkElement fe = currObj as FrameworkElement;
if (fe != null)
{
    fe.BringIntoView();
}
else
{
    FrameworkContentElement fce = currObj as FrameworkContentElement;
    if (fce != null)
    {
        fce.BringIntoView();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.